# How to specify integration limits in scipy.integrate.trapz or simps?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, numerical-integration

I understand that in scipy.integrate.trapz(y, x=None, dx=1.0, axis=-1) or simps, the min and max values of x (if specified) are taken to be the limits of the integral, but what happens when x=None? It has dx to figure out the spacing in the x values but at what value does it start x?

I tried it with and without x, from which I understand that it starts x values from 0.0 when x is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

> but at what value does it start x

It doesn't matter for integration. You just specify the values of `y` and tell scipy how far the `x`s are apart. Whether they start at -5 or +26 doesn't influence the value of the integral.

Comment: That doesn't seem correct. The area under a curve would change based on the limits of the independent variable. Otherwise, I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.

Comment: Sure, but you don't change the values of the integral. They are always `y` (to the function).